# JRebel 5.6.1 not starting: Throwing java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: weblogic/rmi/spi/HostID error Java8

Tags: java-8, rmi, weblogic12c, jrebel

I am using **JRebel version 5.6.1**. I am trying to start my server on **Java 1.8** and **weblogic 12.2.1**. When I start my server, I get the following error on the console:

```
2015-11-09 11:25:54 JRebel: ERROR java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: weblogic/rmi/spi/HostID
    at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.mE.a(JRebel:1684)
    at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.mE.a(JRebel:1654)
    at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.mJ.a(JRebel:1426)
    at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.mJ.a(JRebel:1325)
    at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.mQ.d(JRebel:1475)
    at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.mP.d(JRebel:866)
    at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.Dr.d(JRebel:63)
    at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.mC.a(JRebel:1554)
    at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.mC.b(JRebel:1017)
    at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.mC.a(JRebel:693)
    at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.mC.a(JRebel:506)
    at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.Dm.process(JRebel:32)
    at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.yQ.a(JRebel:257)
    at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.yQ.a(JRebel:246)
    at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.yQ.a(JRebel:224)
    at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.SDKIntegrationImpl.runBytecodeProcessors(JRebel:127)
    at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.yz.transform(JRebel:45)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:836)
    at com.oracle.classloader.PolicyClassLoader.defineClass(PolicyClassLoader.java:515)
    at com.oracle.classloader.PolicyClassLoader.defineClass(PolicyClassLoader.java:495)
    at com.oracle.classloader.SearchPolicy.defineClass(SearchPolicy.java:115)
    at com.oracle.classloader.search.SearchCodeSources.loadClass(SearchCodeSources.java:174)
    at com.oracle.classloader.search.SearchSequence.loadClass(SearchSequence.java:126)
    at com.oracle.classloader.PolicyClassLoader$1.run(PolicyClassLoader.java:259)
    at com.oracle.classloader.PolicyClassLoader$1.run(PolicyClassLoader.java:257)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.oracle.classloader.PolicyClassLoader.loadClass(PolicyClassLoader.java:256)
    at com.oracle.classloader.weblogic.LaunchClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchClassLoader.java:62)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.DescriptorManager.createRuntimeDescriptor(DescriptorManager.java:127)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.DescriptorManager.getBasicRuntimeDescriptor(DescriptorManager.java:106)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.DescriptorManager.getDescriptor(DescriptorManager.java:66)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.DescriptorManager.getDescriptor(DescriptorManager.java:51)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.OIDManager.makeServerReference(OIDManager.java:192)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.OIDManager.getReplacement(OIDManager.java:173)
    at weblogic.rmi.utils.io.RemoteObjectReplacer.replaceRemote(RemoteObjectReplacer.java:107)
    at weblogic.rmi.utils.io.RemoteObjectReplacer.replaceObject(RemoteObjectReplacer.java:90)
    at weblogic.rmi.extensions.server.ServerHelper.exportObject(ServerHelper.java:234)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.OIDManager.initializeDGCServer(OIDManager.java:229)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.OIDManager.initializeServer(OIDManager.java:236)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.OIDManager.initialize(OIDManager.java:220)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.RMIServerService.start(RMIServerService.java:52)
    at weblogic.server.AbstractServerService.postConstruct(AbstractServerService.java:76)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor7.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.invoke(ReflectionHelper.java:1262)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.postConstructMe(ClazzCreator.java:332)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:374)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:85)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2072)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:114)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1213)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1144)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:643)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333)
    at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54)
    at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:617)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:397)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346)
```

2015-11-09 11:25:54 JRebel: ERROR Class 'weblogic/rmi/internal/BasicRuntimeDescriptor' could not be processed by 'com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.Dm@77e6b35e': java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lan
NotFoundException: weblogic/rmi/spi/HostID
        at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.mE.a(JRebel:1684)
        at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.mE.a(JRebel:1654)
        at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.mJ.a(JRebel:1426)
        at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.mJ.a(JRebel:1325)
        at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.mQ.d(JRebel:1475)
        at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.mP.d(JRebel:866)
        at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.Dr.d(JRebel:63)
        at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.mC.a(JRebel:1554)
        at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.mC.b(JRebel:1017)
        at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.mC.a(JRebel:693)
        at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.mC.a(JRebel:506)
        at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.Dm.process(JRebel:32)
        at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.yQ.a(JRebel:257)
        at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.yQ.a(JRebel:246)
        at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.yQ.a(JRebel:224)
        at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.SDKIntegrationImpl.runBytecodeProcessors(JRebel:127)
        at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.yz.transform(JRebel:45)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:836)
        at com.oracle.classloader.PolicyClassLoader.defineClass(PolicyClassLoader.java:515)
        at com.oracle.classloader.PolicyClassLoader.defineClass(PolicyClassLoader.java:495)
        at com.oracle.classloader.SearchPolicy.defineClass(SearchPolicy.java:115)
        at com.oracle.classloader.search.SearchCodeSources.loadClass(SearchCodeSources.java:174)
        at com.oracle.classloader.search.SearchSequence.loadClass(SearchSequence.java:126)
        at com.oracle.classloader.PolicyClassLoader$1.run(PolicyClassLoader.java:259)
        at com.oracle.classloader.PolicyClassLoader$1.run(PolicyClassLoader.java:257)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.oracle.classloader.PolicyClassLoader.loadClass(PolicyClassLoader.java:256)
        at com.oracle.classloader.weblogic.LaunchClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchClassLoader.java:62)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.DescriptorManager.createRuntimeDescriptor(DescriptorManager.java:127)
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.DescriptorManager.getBasicRuntimeDescriptor(DescriptorManager.java:106)
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.DescriptorManager.getDescriptor(DescriptorManager.java:66)
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.DescriptorManager.getDescriptor(DescriptorManager.java:51)
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.OIDManager.makeServerReference(OIDManager.java:192)
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.OIDManager.getReplacement(OIDManager.java:173)
        at weblogic.rmi.utils.io.RemoteObjectReplacer.replaceRemote(RemoteObjectReplacer.java:107)
        at weblogic.rmi.utils.io.RemoteObjectReplacer.replaceObject(RemoteObjectReplacer.java:90)
        at weblogic.rmi.extensions.server.ServerHelper.exportObject(ServerHelper.java:234)
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.OIDManager.initializeDGCServer(OIDManager.java:229)
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.OIDManager.initializeServer(OIDManager.java:236)
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.OIDManager.initialize(OIDManager.java:220)
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.RMIServerService.start(RMIServerService.java:52)
        at weblogic.server.AbstractServerService.postConstruct(AbstractServerService.java:76)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor7.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.invoke(ReflectionHelper.java:1262)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.postConstructMe(ClazzCreator.java:332)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:374)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:228)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:85)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2072)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:114)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:88)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1213)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1144)
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:643)
        at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348)
        at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333)
        at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54)
        at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:617)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:397)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346)

I get the initial message from JRebel but after that the above error comes and I am not able to update any of my classes. Also I do not get any message that folders would be monitored for changes.

Please help me with pointers to resolve the issue.

Comment: As a ZeroTurnaround insider I can tell that it looks to be JRebel defect and its being worked on by the dev team. You should get updates about the fix progress soon.

Comment: @Margus Is there a defect logged. Please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been fixed in JRebel nightly build. Nightly build can be downloaded from https://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/download/nightly-build/

Comment: This is version 6.2.7. I was hoping that the same could be fixed for version 5.6.1 also

Comment: Did the fix in nightly build work for you?
ZeroTurnaround keeps all the old versions unchanged and adds new changes only to new versions. If 5.6.1 is changed then it would not be 5.6.1 anymore.

Comment: Agree..but I am not sure if I would be able to move to higher versions immediately. Anyways thanks for the help!

Comment: :: After having used the nightly build, I am getting the following messages on my server console: `CHANGE
E:\Oracle\diag\tnslsnr\myid\listener\alert\log.xml
CHANGE
E:\Oracle\diag\tnslsnr\myid\listener\trace\listener.log
CHANGE
E:\Oracle\diag
CHANGE
E:\Oracle\diag\tnslsnr\myid\listener\alert\log.xml
CHANGE
E:\Oracle\diag\tnslsnr\myid\listener\trace\listener.log`. Have they been introduced by Jrebel? If so, are they harmless?

Comment: These do not look like JRebel messages. Do they disappear if you start the server without JRebel javaagent?

Comment: Yes they disappear if I start my server without the JRebel javaagent. But I have found a workaround for it. I use PowerCmd tool for all my command prompts. When I start my server in that tool, I get the messages. If I start my server using a standalone command prompt, I am not getting these messages. So I am starting the server using the standalone command prompt.

Comment: I am getting another issue: `JRebel: ERROR Class 'org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.init.JerseyServletContainerInitializer' could not be processed by org.zeroturnaround.jrebel.jersey2.cbp.JerseyServletContainerInit
ializerCBP@sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@14dad5dc: org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.CannotCompileException: [source error] no such class: JrWrappingResourceConfig at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.CtNewMethod.make(JRebel:79)
 at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.CtNewMethod.make(JRebel:45)
 at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.CtMethod.make(JRebel:132)`

Comment: Best way to have these issues resolved is to write directly to the support@zeroturnaround.com. Are you using Weblogic perhaps?  
Can you send the full error stack trace with jrebel.log in trace level to support@zeroturnaround.com for deeper investigation? Trace log will be generated wuth JVM argument -Drebel.log=trace.